# Gstreamer error during installing gst-plugins-gl on imx6 sabrelite using LTIB

Tags: gstreamer

Iam trying to build uImage for imx6 sabrelite board for gstreamer. iam trying to build gst-plugins-gl but im getting errors as follows
host is arm-unknown-linux-gnu
`checking for fbGetDisplay in -lEGL... no`
`checking for X... no`
`checking X11/Xlib.h usability... no`
`checking X11/Xlib.h presence... no`
`checking for X11/Xlib.h... no`
`configure: cannot find X11 development files`
`checking EGL/egl.h usability... no`
`checking EGL/egl.h presence... no`
`checking for EGL/egl.h... no`
`checking GL/gl.h usability... no`
`checking GL/gl.h presence... no`
`checking for GL/gl.h... no`
`configure: error: GL or EGL is required, consider installing libgl1-mesa-dev`

```
i installed libgl1-mesa-dev after recompiling it again i am still getting the same errors please guide me how can i build it sucessfully
```

Answer (score 0):

To build `gst-plugins-gl`, you need to select the `gpu-viv-bin-mx6q` package (in LTIB configure, which you can access using `./ltib -c`).

The error you're seeing ("consider installing libgl1-mesa-dev") is referring to your target platform filesystem, not your Linux host.